# Encoding on read textual data from binary file

Tags: c, encoding, console

I read the block from binary file (I know that this block contains textual data).

```
fread(textual_info_buffer,sizeof(unsigned char),3200, dataFileHandler); 

    for (int i = 0; i < 3200; i++)
    {
        printf("%c%s", textual_info_buffer[i], " ");
    }
```

As a result I've got:

**├ @ ё @ ├**

while I expect:

**C 1 C**

The codes I get for these symbols are:

**195 64 241 64 195**

The question is how to read (or print) it correctly with appropriate encoding to get expected values? Should I got current encoding and convert to it?

Thank you!

Comment: How many items were read by `fread`? There is no check, you just assume it worked. You are also assuming the block contains ASCII text.

Comment: Yep, thank you, I just recreated it:  fread(textual_header_buffer,sizeof(unsigned char),3200, segyFileHandler); 
it returns 3200. But the problem with encoding is the same.

Comment: This smells like an X-Y question. It's unusual to mix binary and textual methods.

Comment: So from 5 bytes you expect 3 ASCII characters?

Comment: Yes, but I have one binary file and it contains both binary and textual information.

Comment: @Siguza, but I thought spaces also counted, don't they?

Comment: @SergeySvetlikov Yes, but you add those manually in your code. So you say your expected output would be (using `.` for space) `C...1...C.`?

Comment: @Siguza, yep. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: WeatherVane is probably correct. If you have binary information, then it should be interpreted as binary. If it's textual, then it should be interpreted as textual. Are you unable to determine whether the data is text or binary in a given context? It's unusual to do something like "data: textData" and then on the next line do "data: binaryData" without some sort of indication of whether the data is text or binary. Basically, your file should be structured in some way, else it is unlikely to be able to be parsed by a machine.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune, ok, but anyway - what I do incorrectly? I just read info to buffer and now try to get data from this buffer.

Comment: If you have mixed binary and textual data, it's presumably come from some `struct` written to a file, rather than arbitrary sequential writes of text and binary data. So show us the struct, how the file was made, and the  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which exhibits the fault, and your attempts to read the data back into a `struct`.